# HTML/PHP : how can I have multiple form that send informations to the same page?

Tags: php, html, forms

My problem is this :

I got 2 forms that are supposed to send different informations to the same page (via POST method). Each form has a submit button. However when I press any of the button, information from both forms are sent to the page.
Is it normal or is there something that I do wrong ?

Comment: Could you please post your HTML?

Comment: Do both forms use the same `<form>` tag? As @Xanco says, this will be easier to debug if we can see the code.

Comment: can you place the HTML code on your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can already tell you without looking at your HTML.

You have to properly close the first form before opening the second. Easy mistake to make.

```
<form method="post" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" name="something" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="page.php">
    <input type="text" name="somethingelse" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just figured this out by myself. Crazy how you could be able to solve my problem without the code though.

Thanks man !

Comment: @user3066615 If this answered your question be sure to mark it by clicking the check mark. You get 2 points for marking an answer.